# Access firebase library function across multiple files

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am making a website using firebase for backend data storage and user authentication.  I have all my firebase setup and imports in one file.  Each page of the website has its own script files which will use different firebase functions.

Right now I am working on a login page which needs to use the firebase auth function.

Is there a way to access the auth function (and other firebase functions) from a separate file or do I need to include all the content of firebase-sdk.js in all of my files?

I am using a basic html environment with no frameworks or bundlers

In my code I have a file named firebase-sdk.js that contains all the import statements for the firebase features I will be using.

```
//Import firebase
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-app.js";

//Import firebase features
import { getFirestore,
    collection,
    addDoc,
    onSnapshot,
    doc,
    updateDoc,
    deleteDoc
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"

import { getAuth, 
    onAuthStateChanged,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-auth.js"

//Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = { --- };

//Initialise firestore
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//Initialise features
const auth = getAuth(app)
const db = getFirestore(app)
```

I have another file, login.js, where I want to use the firebase auth function, but the program can not find the definition of the auth function.

```
const loginBtn = document.getElementById('id_submit_login_btn')

const loginBtnPressed = async () => {
    const loginEmail = document.getElementById('id_email_entry').value
    const loginPassword = document.getElementById('id_password_entry').value

    const userCredentials = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, loginEmail, loginPassword)
    console.log(userCredentials.user)
}

loginBtn.addEventListener('click', loginBtnPressed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to import in every file where the imported symbol needs to be used.  An import in one file doesn't make the imported symbols available in any other files - they are "scoped" to the file in the same way that `let` or `const` variables are scoped to the block where you define them, and not outside of it.

This has nothing to do with Firebase. It is just how JavaScript works.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, thanks for the help.